# "От безысходности" или "из безысходности"

Tags: предлоги

> Я **из** безысходности остался тут.

или

> Я **от** безысходности остался тут.

Какой вариант предпочтительней?

Comment: please, put some effort in asking a question. "Phrase a" or "phrase b" is not enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Правилен вариант "**(остался) *от* безысходности**". В *данном контексте* предлог указывает на *внешнюю причину* (отчего, почему - **оттого**, что не было выхода, что *ситуация* была безысходной). Предлог "**из**" указывает на *внутренний мотив* (остался **из ревности**, **из сочувствия** к кому-то, **из** каких-то **соображений**). Если изменить предлог на "*из*", то аргументация в данном предложении с объективной ситуации переключается на *мотив* и выходит парадокс: оставаясь там, человек "**исходил из безысходности**". 
Но дело не в абсолютной несочетаемости предлога и слова: в другом контексте (*откуда куда*) сочетание "из безысходности" возможно (в этом примере даже нельзя изменить предлог на "от"):

> **Из** безысходности наркотических сновидений он вернулся **в** здоровую
>   жизнь.